# Как лучше обновлять информацию в контроле из процесса, запущенного в отдельном потоке? Через события, BeginInvoke или через async? Или еще как-то?

Tags: c#, winforms, многопоточность

Программа запускает длительный процесс в отдельном потоке. Как сейчас, на Шарпе 8-9 технологичнее всего обновлять из потока ListBox на форме информацией о стадиях и успехе выполняемого процесса? Как лучше перезапустить процесс-поток в случае неудачного выполнения? Через исключения в потоке, отлавливая из в главном потоке? Или еще как-то?

Comment: Это три вопроса, а не один.

Comment: 1) `IProgress<T>` 2) `Task.Run` 3) `try-catch`

Answer (score 2):

Как вам верно сказали в комментариях, у вас три вопроса.

1. **Как обновлять UI?**

   Долгоиграющий фоновый процесс относится к модели, и он сообщает о результатах как ему удобно. Если результат один, скорее всего он возвращается в виде промиса `Task<T>`. Если результатов много, скорее всего вам нужно `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` или `IObservable<T>`. Если у вас числомолотилка, может быть, возвращать стоит синхронно материальный результат.

   Часть кода, которая маршаллирует результаты в UI-поток и запускает процесс обновления UI, принадлежит к бизнес-логике. Для `Task<T>`, например, вообще никаких дополнительных действий не нужно, для `IObservable<T>` вам нужно `ObserveOn` и т. д.
2. **Как лучше перезапустить фоновое задание?**

   В 2020 году вовсе не нужно использовать сырые потоки. Используйте промисы (`Task` или `Task<T>`). Для сообщения об ошибке вам нужны исключения, `Task` займётся маршаллированием исключений в нужный поток за вас.
3. **Использовать ли исключения для управления фоновыми заданиями?**

   Конечно, исключения и try/catch.